# How to prevent users from easily accessing localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am creating a login/signup form for my html blog website. I've managed to create the user information using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`. I would store it whenever someone creates an account, and get it whenever someone wants to log in.

I haven't made the sign out or actual user page yet, but that is not my problem. The problem is that it is too easy for someone to steal passwords or clear all the account data using `localStorage.clear()`

Here is an HTML example:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Accounts</title>
</head>

<body>
    <article>
        <h1>Log In</h1>
        <input type="text" id="signin-username" placeholder="Username" value="">
        <input type="password" id="signin-password" placeholder="Password" value="">
        <button type="submit" onclick="signin()">Sign In</button>
        <!------------------------------------>
        <h1>Create Account</h1>
        <input type="text" id="create-username" placeholder="Username" value="">
        <input type="password" id="create-password" placeholder="Password" value="">
        <button type="submit" onclick="create()">Create Account</button>
    </article>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the javascript for it:

```
var a = localStorage.length;

function signin() {
    var name = document.getElementById('signin-username').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('signin-password').value;

    if (name === '' && pass === '') {
        console.log('Please provide your account details')
    }

    else if (name === '') {
        console.log('Please provide your username!');
    }

    else if (pass === '') {
        console.log('Please provide your password!');
    }

    else {
        var ii;
        for (ii = 0; ii < a; ii++) {
            if (name === localStorage.key(ii)) {
                console.log('Logged in as ' + name);
                ii > a
            }
            else {
                console.log('Account Does Not Exist!')
            }
        }
    }
};

function create() {

    var username = document.getElementById('create-username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('create-password').value;

    if (username === '' && password === '') {
        console.log('Invalid Username and Password')
    }

    else if (username === '') {
        console.log('Invalid Username');
    }

    else if (password === '') {
        console.log('Invalid Password');
    }

    else {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            if (username === localStorage.key(i)) {
                console.log('Username Exists!');
            }
            else {
                localStorage.setItem(username, password)
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I had to post The Full thing in order for it to make sense. 
Anyone have suggestions, like user cookies, for storing data?
You can even redirect me to a login example!

Comment: For anyone asking, i didn't make a snippet as the Stackoverflow snippets are sandboxed.

Comment: It is a terrible idea to store a password anywhere, let alone in the browser. The password should be hashed and you only store the hash in your DATABASE, not the browser. The way session management usually works is that you only store a token in the browser, which is transmitted to your server through Authorization header or a Cookie. The server resolves this token to a user and sends back the user data

Comment: i was originally thinking of using php and SQL but I don't know those things yet.

Comment: Now that I think about it, do you or anyone know how to get started on creating a basic login or sign up form? I would thuroughly appreciate it.

Comment: Well than you should learn those things first. You CAN NOT have an account system just with HTML & JS, let alone a secure one. You need some server to handle that. Your only other option if you don't want to set up a full authentication server is to pay for existing solutions like Auth0 (which is also best used with a server) https://auth0.com/

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've managed to create the user information using `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

LocalStorage is "local" to the web browser. Data stored in LocalStorage is not shared with the web server, or with other web browsers viewing the site. It makes no sense to store account data in these locations, because doing so will result in an "account" that only exists on one computer.

(SessionStorage works similarly, except it disappears when the browser is closed -- so it's even less useful for your purposes.)

If you want to allow users to create accounts on your web site, you will need some sort of code running on the web server to implement these accounts. There is no way to implement this functionality entirely in client-side Javascript.